# jquery 1.11 tabs disable cache not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I have migrated from jquery 1.8.4 to 1.11, since then having issue with the cache behaviours in IE 11.

In 1.8.4 to disable cache I used which worked pretty well

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({ajaxOptions: { cache: false }
```

But now as cache property is no longer supported the data is always loaded from the cache. I have changed the code but no effect. This works in Firefox but not in IE

```
var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs({ajaxOptions: { cache: false },
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
            ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            var link = $(ui.tab).find("a").attr("href");
            var index = link.lastIndexOf("?"); 
            var timestamp = Date.now();
            if(index > 0) {
                link = link.substring(0, index);  
            }
            link = link + "?ts_=" +  timestamp;
            ui.ajaxSettings.url = link;

        }
```